# print in an archive with python

Tags: python, external, archive

I have a problem with a litlle program in python:
what I want is to write on a archive called text numbers from 0 to 10, but the program give me error all the time and doesn't print anything.

```
i=0
while(i<11):
    outfile = open('text.txt', 'a') 
    outfile.write('\n'+i)
    outfile.close()
    i=i+1
```

I tried puting

```
outfile.write('\n'+i)
outfile.write('\n',i)
outfile.write('\n'),i
outfile.write(i)
```

but not a single one of them works, can you tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the error you're getting involves concatenating a string with an integer.

try:

```
outfile.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're openning/closing your file at each iteration of while-loop. Why overdo things? You can easily do the job, once the file is open.

Also, you try to write *'\n'* (which is a string) plus *i* (which is an integer). That's wrong, and you need to convert your *i* into string too.

Try this code:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(11):
        f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a file that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Did you try it this way?

```
>>> fo = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     fo.write(str(i)+"\n")
>>> fo.close()
```

The error you probably are getting is this :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Which is because you are trying to concatenate a string and an integer. COnvert you integer ( `i`) into a string by enclosing it with `str()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while(i<11):
    outfile = open('text.txt', 'a') 
    outfile.write('\n'+str(i))
    outfile.close()
    i=i+1
```

I am getting a text.txt with 0-10 on seperate lines with a blank line at the top.